# How can split a varchar in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

is possible to separate a varchar in mysql and display the result in new columns in a select sentence.?
and how can do it?

Some like this tables:  (select * from patterns)

```
PATTERNS
AA00BB99
```

and Get this in a :

```
 NEWCOLUMN1  NEWCOLUMN2  NEWCOLUMN3  NEWCOLUMN4
    AA           00         BB          99
```

Comment: always 4 groups of 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your always grabbing the same pattern (the first two, then the 3rd and 4th, then the 5th and 6th, then the 7th and 8th characters) you can use `SUBSTRING()`

```
SELECT substring(yourfield, 1, 2) AS NewColumn1,
    substring(yourfield, 3, 2) AS NewColumn2,
    substring(yourfield, 5, 2) AS NewColumn3,
    substring(yourfield, 7, 2) AS NewColumn4
FROM patterns
```